# Is it possible to update an object initialized in a superclass from a subclass?

Tags: python, inheritance, subclass, superclass

So lets say I have a class:

```
class SuperClass():
    def __init__(self, number):
       self._inputnumber = number
       self._initallist = []
```

And then I want to build subclasses of this class which have methods that can add items to the initialized list, read items from it, or remove items from it. For example.

```
class SubClass(SuperClass):
     def __init__(self, number, current_line, new_line): 
        self._number = number
        self._thisline = current_line
        self._gohere = new_line
     def execute(self):
        (SuperClass._initallist).append(self._thisline + 1)
```

This is a bit of a rough example of what I am trying to do. I want to be able to have my initial list available for a couple of classes so that they can both act upon it as shown above. What ends up happening in my case, though, is that I get an AttributeError saying that my SuperClass doesn't have the named attribute.

```
AttributeError: type object 'SuperClass' has no attribute '_initiallist'
```

Any tips on how to do this? Is it even possible or do I have to do something else to achieve this result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I want to build subclasses of this class which have methods that can add items to the initialized list,..."

Are you saying you want the subclasses to inherit the *instance attribute* `_initiallist` and provide methods to act upon it? If this is the case then *instances* of the subclasses will each have an `_initiallist` attribute *but* each `_initiallist` for each instance of the class will be a different list.

In that case the solution is as **zhangyangyu** described.

---

"I want to be able to have my initial list available for a couple of classes so that they can both act upon it as shown above."

Based on the title, I could interpret this as: I want the `_initiallist` attribute of some *instance* of the superclass to be available for *instances* of a couple of subclasses so they can all act upon the same exact list.

You could do that if `_initiallist` is a class attribute, or you could pass an instance of the superclass as an `__init__` argument when instantiating the subclass, as far as I know currently.

Also, this would mean that the two classes in your example do not posses an **is a** relationship, but rather, your superclass is really a sharedobject (AFAIK).

If you make it a class attribute then you lose some flexibility because then different instances of the superclass will all have an attribute `_initiallist` that points to the same exact list. Where as if you keep it as an instance attribute and pass an instance of the superclass to the subclass as an argument (as a shared object), then you can still achieve what you want to do and still have the flexibility to create multiple instances of your shared object.

```
class SharedObject(object):

    def __init__(self, number):
        self._inputnumber = number
        self._initiallist = []


class Client(object):

    def __init__(self, obj, current_line, new_line):
        self._sharedobj = obj
        self._thisline = current_line
        self._gohere = new_line

    def execute(self):
        self._sharedobj._initiallist.append(self._thisline + 1)
```

Comment: What exactly is obj in this context? Is it the SharedObject class?

Comment: It's an instance of the `SharedObject` class. I should've actually named it `sharedobj` just like the attribute. Does it capture at all what you're trying to do?

Comment: It ended up working in the end, I realized I didn't really need inheritance and could just pass the SharedObject as it were into my execute statement as a parameter and then execute would be able to act upon the initiallist

Answer (score 2):

`_initallist` is an instance attribute, you can not access it by `Super._initallist`.

I think what you want to do is below. You need to init `SuperClass` in the `SubClass`. And I think if this is a right **is-one** relation, there need to be a `number` in `SubClass`.

```
class SuperClass():
    def __init__(self, number):
       self._inputnumber = number
       self._initallist = []

class SubClass(SuperClass):
     def __init__(self, number, current_line, new_line):
        SuperClass.__init__(self, number) 
        self._thisline = current_line
        self._gohere = new_line
     def execute(self):
        self._initallist.append(self._thisline + 1)
```

Comment: This is the right basic idea, but a better alternative would be to use Python's recommended new-style classes by writing `class SuperClass(object):` and then call `super(SubClass,self).__init__(number)` from `SubClass.__init__()`

Comment: Yes. The built-in `super` is a better method.

Comment: You are right in that this is an is-one relationship, and this almost works, but like RussW said, this gives me a new list instance for each sub class. So when I call the method twice, adding a print statement for the list at the end, it gives me two lists with one number each, as opposed to having two items the second time.

Answer (score 1):

Just do `self._initiallist.append(self._thisline + 1)`

Comment: I have tried doing that as well. In that case I get another AttributeError saying my SubClass does not have the attribute _initiallist.

Comment: How are you initializing the SuperClass/SubClass?